# jquery change event not working in select option

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a `html` option list similar to below:

```
<select id="qualification">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

And the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#qualification').chnage(function(){
        alert('sd');
    });
});
```

But when I change the `select` options, its not alerting anything ! What is the reason ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kE4X7/5/)

Comment: `change()` not `chnage()`

Comment: Aren't you getting an error in the Javascript console, complaining that the `chnage` method doesn't exist?

Comment: chnage check the syntax it should be change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `chnage` to `change` and it should be fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#qualification').change(function(){
        alert('sd');
    });
});
```

Comment: Lucky, the easiest question ever.

Comment: Lucky you didn't write 'chnage chnage to change'

Comment: @Dharman & Lave Loos :P